# Should very old questions from regular users be able to be flagged for review?

Tags: discussion

I have had a number of answers reviewed recently that were quite old - the most recent was 5 years old.

Does it seem reasonable that, at some point, old answers should be made 'unreviewable'?  Especially when the most recent had a score of 1 - who's going to read that one ;)

I'm not even sure that the 'regular users' part is germane.

Comment: love the down votes without any reason - thanks

Comment: Meta votes are different... it doesn't necessarily mean you have a bad question, they can simply mean someone disagrees with your question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: (You won't see *your* edit in revisions because you submitted it in the 5 mins grace period.)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - I see what you did there :(

Answer (score 9):

I've noticed an awful lot of old posts floating through the Low Quality review lately.
Personally I think its a good thing...

In the before time, in the long long ago, Stack Overflow was a bit more permissive in what was considered an acceptable post. As the site has grown and grown up, the rules have tightened up a bit to combat a daily barrage of garbage.

I think it is important to go back through the old stuff to make sure that these posts meet with the current standards, partially because the old stuff sets an example for the new stuff.

When new users see old posts from "high rep users" that don't meet the current standard they aren't likely to understand the history. They see a link only answer or an off-topic question and just think:
"If they can do it, why can't I do it..."

Comment: Of course, some of that rather troubling old content will be worth considering for a historical lock instead of deletion, but closing is the first step.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that rewriting history is a good thing.  Just because the site was more permissive back then, doesn't mean that content should be 'cleaned up' to cover existing rules.  If, for no other reason, you are punishing people retroactively for things that were perfectly acceptable at the time.

Comment: Also, there's no guarantee that things won't change again to be more permissive, but because of a brief period of "tyranny" much of the content is gone.  (I use "tyranny" not in the literal meaning, but simply to indicate and overly strict period of time).  To paraphrase Santayana, - Those who delete history are doomed to repeat it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we absolutely want to be improving the quality of the content on the site.  The whole design of the site is for content to be found by users through Google, which will rather often be directing users to posts that are not at all recent.  If those questions have inappropriate answers, they should be dealt with appropriately so that these readers coming across the question have the best possible experience.

Posts don't stop being read after they're a few days/weeks/months/years old.

Comment: That brings up an interesting question-  how do you fix old content that just isn't right?  I see a fair number of questions on the Android tag using a particular class posted 3 years ago that kind of works, but has a lot of bugs and loopholes.  But since it has 30 some upvotes and google links to it, it will never go away.  So there's a big negative to keeping the old content too.  And no, downvoting it and leaving a better class isn't a sufficient answer-  it will take years for it to be voted higher than the original, if it ever is.

Comment: @gabe - this is what editing is for. If an answer is no longer correct you could add some editorial information "with version xxx a new class yyy was created which makes this answer unhelpful" type of thing. But better, obviously.

Comment: @GabeSechan Well, first off, it sounds like you're talking about issues that are entirely separate from what the review queues are there to handle.  They're there to handle things like non-answers posted as answers, not answers that are technically incorrect.  Since you brought it up though, the solution for what to do when you see an answer with bugs isn't to try to delete the answer, it's to downvote it, comment, and/or post another answer that is correct.

Comment: @Servy Deleting the answer isn't right, you're correct.  The code works, for some value of works-  if used as an example of how to use the GPS api it isn't too bad.  It was just has a lot of issues-  functions that don't do quite what they say, data that can be incorrect in corner cases, etc.  The problem is its in google's first return, so 4 years later people are still trying to use it and I see a few questions a week on it.  But maybe I should stop hijacking and bring it up as a separate question when I've had time to think through the issue myself a bit more.