# When is a 'Not an answer' answer not a 'Not an answer' answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers, moderation

**Some background:**

I came across an answer of the form

> this has been answered [here](link)

in the [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) review queue and flagged it for deletion since it falls under the category of 'Not An Answer' (c.f. the ["*Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827) meta Stack Overflow question by [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)).

I'd like to think that I'm a good Stack Overflow citizen (until about a week ago, I had around 2900 helpful flags and only 20 declined flags), so I decided to do a search to find similar answers. I searched for [`is:answer "has been answered here"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%22has+been+answered+here%22) - about 450 answers came up. I went through them and raised 33 "Not An Answer" flags over about two hours.

Since then, my declined post flags count has increased from 17 (which I thought was high - though I have flagged 3286 posts/comments - see below) to 27 - in a few days. Pretty much all of them come with the explanation:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I'm not sure that I understand the decision of the moderator(s) here - to me, they *are* "Not An Answer" answers.

---

**Some of my recently declined flags which I am certain are "not an answer" answers:**

---

- [(accepted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2296980/1364007) to ["*multiple app.config files*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2296912/1364007) answered Feb 19 '10 at 14:31:

  > I believe this has been answered here, if not this will give you an idea of how to go about editing multiple app.config files:
  >   [How to modify .NET config files during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289773/how-to-modify-net-config-files-during-installation)

---

- Deleted: <strike>[(accepted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3749751/1364007)</strike> to ["*jQuery datepicker validating date ranges between two dates in any format*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3710465/1364007) answered Sep 20 '10 at 8:29:

  > This has been answered here:
  >
  > http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validating-date-range-in-any-format-with-jquery-ui-datepickers#14737000001389001

---

- Deleted: <strike>[(accepted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6973203/1364007)</strike> to ["*How to use Morphia with Java / GWT*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6669096/1364007) answered Aug 7 '11 at 13:49:

  > This has been answered here already: http://groups.google.com/group/morphia/browse_thread/thread/f161d8b0225b1a4e/a174e7857956cf3e

---

- Deleted: <strike>[(accepted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2341403/1364007)</strike> to ["*Sprintf for Actionscript 3?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2341355/1364007) answered Feb 26 '10 at 12:05:

  > This has been answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198374/is-there-something-like-printf-in-action-script-3)

---

- Deleted: <strike>[(accepted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828523/1364007) to ["*Accessing SAP trough PHP, how is it?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2828331/1364007)</strike> answered May 13 '10 at 16:32:

  > Have you found this yet: http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/EmTech/PHP+and+SAP

---

- Deleted: <strike>[(accepted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941151/1364007) to ["*Listen for SysLog in .NET*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1934655/1364007)</strike> answered Dec 21 '09 at 16:36:

  > Great answer [HERE](http://blog.stevienova.com/2005/04/08/how-to-make-your-own-syslog-sever-in-vbnet/)

---

The only thing I can see that I could have done wrong is to flag these as "Not An Answer" without adding a comment for the moderator - perhaps the standard

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

which gets added as part of the "Low Quality Posts" review queue.

---

**My question:**

Was the reason that my flags were rejected that

1. My flurry of flags that day caused them to be handled differently,
2. My "Not An Answer" flags are not "Not An Answer" (in which case I'd like to know how I can handle these differently in future),
3. The answers were old so aren't held to today's standards (though I have been led to believe that all posts should be held to today's standards - e.g. ["*Should very old questions from regular users be able to be flagged for review?*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262903/1364007)),
4. The answers are accepted answers, so are treated differently,
5. Something else I've not thought of.

I'm not posting this because to *whine* about the declined flags - I really am interested in knowing what I can do to avoid them in future.

---

For the record, my flag (2977 helpful) breakdown at the moment is:

- **Post flags:** 3,190 (2,884 helpful, 22 waiting for review, 27 declined, 101 disputed, 156 aged away)
- **Comment flags:** 15 (14 helpful, 1 declined)
- **Spam flags:** 64 (63 helpful, 1 declined)
- **Offensive flags:** 17 (16 helpful, 1 declined)

---

**Rebuttal to the "Possible duplicate of [*"Disputed not an answer flags"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270710/1364007) flag**:

I don't think that this is a duplicate because the *reason* that the author of the other question marked the questions as "Not An Answer" was because the answers didn't directly answer the question (in the OP's opinion). My flags, *I believe*, come under the "Not An Answer" category as defined by the "*Your answer is in another castle*" post. Please *do* correct me if I've misinterpreted it (which may well be the case). [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) suggests [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1364007) that

> The rule-of-thumb here is to strip the markup; if you can still regard it as an (attempted) answer without the link, it is still an answer and should not be flagged.

I would argue that without the link, the answers do **not** answer the question - "This has been answered" is not an answer to a question, but a comment.

Comment: Interesting. I flagged [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/352501/1842065), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6612826/1842065) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/467286/1842065) LOA as NAA about a week ago. Result: 1 disputed and 2 declined (same reason).

Comment: I think I saw the Jon Skeet one, thought it was not an answer, but didn't have the courage of my convictions to actually suggest deletion in case it was a review audit and I'd fail by suggesting deletion - I ended up skipping it instead.

Comment: I think SO considers that technically, it is an answer: just a bad quality one. I'm used to flag this kind of "answer" as VLQ and it's usually not disputed and they're quickly closed by the community. // Personnally I think these should be closed as NAA, but I understand their point.

Comment: this post and its comments cost me -9 points. Guess I need to add [meta-tag:link-only-answers] to ignored tags, to avoid leaking rep

Comment: Don't worry @gnat, everyone leaks, the thing is in the right way/place ;P

Comment: Oh, we're doing this again.

Comment: At least one of those flags was to another stackoverflow question, which is explicitly allowed (it's not another castle, it's a different room in the same castle).  Although, it should probably have been flagged a duplicate, linking to another question is also acceptable.

Comment: Most inceptionous title ever.

Comment: @gnat - I'm not sure I understand - *how* has this post (and its comments) made you lose rep? None of the questions or answers I mention are/were yours.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I lost rep on voting the answers (the way these deserved)

Comment: @gnat - ah - I see.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: Why would an *answer* that's just a dupe-flag be explicitly allowed? Where is this explicit allowance recorded, so I can strenuously argue against it? If two SO questions have the same answer, they are (for practical purposes, and perhaps even literally always) duplicate questions, and should **only** be flagged accordingly. Which leaves a comment before the closure. An answer that should be a comment is ... not an answer.

Comment: Is "Is this not a real question?" question not a real "this is not a real question" question? :-)

Comment: @NathanTuggy - if you look at the answer, then look at the user, you will see that he has been a member for 5 years, 9 months.  The answer was posted 5 years and 9 months ago.  Chances are, he did not have enough rep to post a comment or flag.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: Someone who doesn't have enough rep to post a comment should ... *not post a comment as an answer*. The mistake is of course forgivable, but that doesn't change what we should do with the result.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, this is for what `not enough rep for comment` restriction is. Not for allow to comment as an answer. If we want to allow this for guys with small rep, we should to remove initial restriction.

Comment: @vp_arth - flag it for conversion to a comment then, and marking it a dupe.  What should NOT happen is deleting it, and leaving the question unanswered.  Linking to other questions on SO has always been allowed.

Comment: if the question is answered by the answer to another question, surely the question is also a duplicate of the other question?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, let me say that you're not doing a bad job in flagging. Over the last two weeks, your "not an answer" flags have been marked helpful 132 times and declined only 7 times, which is a 95% hit rate. Several other people have been running similar queries over this period and haven't been as discriminating as you are.

I'm not a huge fan of the stated policy of deleting link-based answers that provide no other context, because I hate removing content that people have found valuable. I feel like we're causing the damage we're trying to prevent by going back to old answers with working links and deleting them just to follow some strict protocol.

That said, many of the answers you flagged were blatant advertisements for someone's personal blog, didn't add anything at all to the existing detailed, or pointed out duplicate questions. Few were upvoted, and I have less of a problem removing those.

I believe that a few of the ones you marked above were good candidates to be removed. If an accepted answer to a question just says "I solved it by using the answer here" and links to another Stack Overflow question, the asker is making a pretty strong statement that their question is a duplicate of another. I have no problem with removing that answer, converting it to a comment, and then marking the question as a duplicate. You lose no information in that transaction.

Where I struggle with things are the couple of accepted answers that you point out where someone says an external resource (that still exists) solved their problem, accepts that answer, and there are no other answers left. Were we to delete that answer, an answered question becomes unanswered, and future visitors won't get any help from it.

The ideal situation would be for the answer to be edited to include a summary of what solved the problem, and people often do that when prodded by a comment, but short of that I personally don't like to delete answers like this. Converting this to a comment isn't great, as it removes the accept mark and leaves the question as unanswered when it really was.

Different moderators will handle flags on accepted answers differently, so you will see some variability there. Like I said, most of your flags weren't controversial and were easy to handle. Flagging accepted or highly voted answers for removal in general tends to lead to a higher rejection rate.

Comment: Why do people not just put these 'answers' into the comment section of the OP?

Comment: @AshleyWrench: Because you need 50 reputation.

Comment: @AshleyWrench - Comments are for information that adds to a post, and not every answer like this makes sense as a comment. Also, many of the answers being flagged now were left years ago, and the standards for what is acceptable in an answer have changed in that time. I know I left answers that are now regarded as "link-only answers" in my first couple of years on the site, and people didn't have a problem with them at that time.

Comment: It's great that the site has progressed, where it once allowed bad answers it no longer does.  This double standard of old, bad answers being allowed though is discouraging to new users who are trying to make helpful contributions (removing bad content).  Shouldn't something be done to bring these answers up to the new standard format, instead of just declining flags from people who haven't been using the site for long periods of time?

Comment: @rogerdeuce: It is not a double standard. If the answer is useful then it is useful whether it follows some rule or not. Ask yourself: does deleting this answer (as it is) make the internet a better place? No rule is perfect: you have to apply your best judgement for each answer. You may argue that the answer would be better if it had followed the rule -- I can agree here (you could leave a comment suggesting to expand the answer or edit the answer yourself to include the necessary context).

Comment: +1 for "The ideal situation would be for the answer to be edited to include a summary of what solved the problem." Could you give that statement some more prominence? Maybe a quick TL;DR at the top?

Comment: **"If a link-only answer is accepted, it is especially important to delete it (converting to a comment if the link isn't broken yet)... When a question has an accepted answer, it looks like it has a definitive answer, and there is not much point in looking for a better one... Sure, the accepted answer might have helped the asker, but it's not going to help future visitors, and the community should not be penalized for that answerer or asker's failing..."** ([quote source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116360/165773))

Comment: @BradLarson - thanks for taking the time to reply. I do appreciate that it's something of a shame to delete link-only answers which are helpful, especially in the case when they are the only answer. Perhaps in those cases, it'd be better if I'd have commented with the "While this link may answer the question..." to prompt the answerer to take action, then either editing myself if I had the appropriate knowledge (and the link was still alive), or flagging. If nothing else, having these rejected flags has taught me to think more about the consequences of indiscriminate flagging.

Comment: @rogerdeuce - as has been said, it's not a double standard - I know I've definitely flagged link-only answers of the form "have you looked at this (link) - it may help you"from back in the day which have since been deleted and the flags marked as helpful.

Comment: **"The ideal situation would be for the answer to be edited to include a summary of what solved the problem..."** Indeed!  I think something people are too timid about editing answers.  Say there is an answer that is, blutnly, a pile of crap anyways.  **Just click the darn ole' "edit" button** on the answer.  Instead of wasting time typing *"You should really include content from that link because .. blah blah"*, just paste in some content from the link. Most of the time the "answer" anyways is from a Disappearing Transient user; so issues of "managing behavior", etc, are utterly irrelevant.

Comment: *I do appreciate that it's something of a shame to delete link-only answers which are helpful, especially in the case when they are the only answer."* just click the Edit button and paste in some-any improved answermatter.  I bet 75% of the time the answerer in question is a disappearing-transient , so it's irrelevant to try to guide behavior with comments (I bet 74% of the time those comments are never even *seen*) - so just click edit and quickly paste in something-anything to improve the answer text at hand.Users in the wild inherently know to just carry on to the linked dupe QAs anyway.

Comment: @JoeBlow Usually it's not so easy as to just edit it. I usually see links to entire blog posts or whole websites, or the link is to the download page of a module or library.

Comment: I don't agree.  It's usually very easy to edit it.  It takes split-seconds to link to any web page (blog, whatever), and scrape some text from it. It's oneof the primal human abilities these days :)  In 90% of cases it's totally trivial.  If it's a link to a library like "cloud dot conversions" or something, simply click edit and state "get a library such as cloud dot conversions".  Assuming that the idea is to **make useful content**, you're already 10 million miles ahead of the usual unfortunately valueless "it's better to add content .. etc" comment.

Comment: @JoeBlow I think adding random sentences from links to link-only answers is not really a substantive improvement on the post.

Comment: @JoeBlow IANAL but simply copying and pasting from some other website is a potential IP violation. You're implicitly covering it with a creative commons license... You _might_ be OK if you carefully and clearly attribute what you've copied and limit it to a small portion of the original. But its something a user should think about, not something to do haphazardly.

Comment: @gnat How in the world is deleting an answer with a useful link better than editing in a relevant summary?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: Word from the top is [quotes are fine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308786/4099598).

Comment: @NathanTuggy I agree. The post echos my comment. You can't just blindly copy & paste.  You need to attribute and just use a key portion. "Then there's a reasonable chance that the quotation falls under fair use. Crucially, you're not claiming ownership of the text you're quoting." (from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308786/221955). But I think adding copied  content to another user's post is a darker shade of grey - it's not bordering on claiming ownership by yourself, but bordering on claiming ownership by the original poster. True, there's edit history, but that's not obvious to all users.

Comment: @JoeBlow - what about the case of videos? If you search for [is:answer "this video"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+"this+video") there's no end of answers that are simply "*this video will help you*" or, even worse, "*this video should/might/may help*". Out of curiosity I followed a few of those links - [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8193488/edit) linked to a **31** minute video... (Continued on next comment)...

Comment: ... (continued) I know [this has been discussed on meta before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278267/1364007) - and the consensus was also that video-only answers are not an answer, but unless I'm **really** desperate I *refuse* to follow video links because they're linear in nature and can't be scanned anywhere nearly as easily for information. The same applies if I'm reviewing - I might end up watching the video only to find its not even relevant.

Comment: Hi Wai.  Regarding videos, it is not 1980.  It is as trivial to copy, link, cloud, extract a video as it is text.  Click to make a screenshot - whatever.  Note that by far the overwhelming thing on the internet .......... is videos (youtube, Netflix, etc).  (***Note that, like you, I - personally, aesthetically - despise video tutorials versus text tutorials.*** If you work with say Unity3D, "video tutorial" culture is a curse. But so what .. I despise fast food and think it should be banned. "So what?" Your technical objection is nonsensical today. You may as well say "no damn images!! heh.)

Comment: BTW you raise good point, it's madness that SO does not include video as it does images.  Completely bizarre.  All wiki/QA sites for what 15? more? years need of course vid/images/text.

Comment: "Where I struggle with things are the couple of accepted answers that you point out where someone says an external resource (that still exists) solved their problem, accepts that answer, and there are no other answers left. " In cases such as this, I don't understand how the **question** has any value to the site, never mind the answer. Either it's "oops I read the documentation and see where I messed up" (essentially a typo), or "I found a third-party tool to do the job" (seeking the recommendation would be off topic).