# Why this NAA flag was declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39227514/3410396) as No An Answer, and later flag was declined.

As it stands now, this answer does not answer the question at all. It looks just like comment on majority of other answers, but is not suited as answer of its own.

Description of flag states:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**, another question, or deleted altogether.

So, why this flag was declined? What I did wrong?

Comment: Don't emphasize on "a comment". Refer to the FAQ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer, you'll notice the word "comment" doesn't even appear there.

Comment: The flag was declined because the moderator who reviewed it doesn't know anything about C++ and assumed that it *was* an answer (albeit a poor one). If the question had been something to the tune of "why isn't this code that calls `setprecision` working?", that would have been a valid answer. A poor one, granted, but as has been established, you shouldn't use NAA flag for poor answers. Nor should you use them for answers that are not *obviously* non-answers, because you cannot assume that the moderator who reviews it has the requisite technical expertise to tell. Just downvote instead.

Comment: @CodyGray that is why the NaA flag does not require subject matter knowledge to handle. It doesn't *have* to answer the question asked. It only has to be able to be seen as an attempt to answer a question conceivably asked on Stack Overflow. Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

Comment: as far as I am concerned that was a comment on another post/just a general comment and not an answer.  I have cast the last delete vote to get rid of it.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is the correct action to be taken. Low quality *answers* qualify as content which should be deleted using delete votes.

Comment: *"It doesn't have to answer the question asked."* This is why we cannot have nice things.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in question is a low-quality partial answer that isn't very good at all, but it is still technically an answer.

An answer qualifying as a comment does not mean that it cannot also be an answer. If a comment -- which can only exist as a comment, not as an answer -- is posted using the answer form, then it is not an answer.

This answer can be seen, outside of the context of the question (because NaA flags are never judged in context of the question) and with no subject matter expertise (which is not required to review NaA flags otherwise there would be a huge amount of NaA flags with no one to review them) an attempted solution to a question conceivably asked on Stack Overflow, however wrong or partial it may be.

Your flag was declined because flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

#### Related

- **[When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)**

  > **Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer.** You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a bad answer, but it is **still an answer**.
- [**Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?**
  [image]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)
- **[When is a 'Not an answer' answer not a 'Not an answer' answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309697/4639281)**

Comment: It is actually *not an answer* in this case. That becomes pretty clear if you read the question. In the apple/castle example, this is a sign that announces the prices of apples at the market. Even if `setprecision` is the answer to the question, the answer doesn't actually state that: it just tells you how you might go about making `setprecision` work if it isn't already working for you. And, of course, even a recommendation to use `setprecision` wouldn't be an answer, either.

Comment: Except that you're wrong. Your entire premise of why "Be sure to include library #include <iomanip> before you'll use setprecision(x)" is  not an answer is that it is technically inaccurate or an altogether wrong answer. flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer. It is most definitely an **attempt to answer a question conceivably asked on Stack Overflow outside of the context of the question**. It doesn't have to answer the question asked, it doesn't have to be complete, it doesn't have to be a good...

Comment: All it has to be is an attempt to answer a question conceivably asked on Stack Overflow. But it's fine if you want to muddy the waters with bad advice. Being that the linked duplicate says pretty much *the exact same thing*, might I suggest voting to reopen the question and posting your own bad answer?

Comment: No, my reason is that *it is completely irrelevant to the question*. I'm not talking about technical accuracy, I'm talking about obvious relevance. Just because you mention something that exists in the language does not make it a valid answer. The standard of being an "attempt" to answer is thoroughly ridiculous. Aside from spam, no one ever posts answers that are not "attempts" to answer. That doesn't make them all answers. *"It doesn't have to answer the question asked"* R U SERIOUS RIGHT NOW??

Comment: Whether you believe that it is thoroughly ridiculous or not is irrelevant. It is the way that it is because if the mod reviewing the flag had to be a subject matter expert to review the flag then the vast majority of the flags would be left unhandled. The fact of the matter, no matter how much you dislike that fact, is that this is not a perfect world and we have to deal with what we have. You should be downvoting, and voting to delete such answers if you think that they should be deleted, not flagging them and expecting moderators to read your mind.

Comment: @Cody *Aside from spam, no one ever posts answers that are not "attempts" to answer*. This is not true. I suggest you start using some moderation tools you have at your disposal, like [new answers to old questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions). You'll find hundreds of posts [that match the 4 examples of the FAQ about NAA flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), and I'm sure we can agree they are not attempts. I just opened it, [this is one of the first posts of page 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39257344).

Comment: I am not saying that anyone has to be a subject matter expert to competently review this flag. You just have to pay attention. I downvote and vote to delete these answers, yes. But I also flag them, so that they can be deleted more quickly. I don't expect people to read my mind. I expect them to read the answer and see plain as day that it is completely irrelevant to the question. @Tunaki, they *are* attempts. The person who posted that answer was attempting to answer the question. Granted, it's a silly semantic argument, but that is the very same argument Tiny Giant is making here.

Comment: I fail to see the silly semantic argument for considering "Do you have a solution for this?" answer as an attempt to answer @Cody.

Comment: @CodyGray A question cannot possibly be an answer, as such it is not an answer. You're deliberately misinterpreting the arguments made here, and the official guidance so that you can muddy the waters. This attitude is not helpful to any user who would like to avoid a flag ban.