# Why was this spam flag declined for an incoherent post with a link to a video?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I recently flagged [this (now deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075130/regex-url-blogger) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HNKt.png)) as spam, but the flag was declined with the message

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Why is this post not spam? At first, I thought the OP was trying to get someone to write him a regular expression, but then I realized that there wasn't a coherent question there and the only purpose of the post seemed to be to promote the linked video.

Comment: did you see the video?

Comment: No, I don't normally click on links that look spammy.

Comment: That's definitely fair enough!

Comment: Screenshot for the mortals..?

Comment: @Kyll https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HNKt.png

Comment: Looks like the OP deleted the question by themselves. That surely wouldn't have been done if the post was intended by the OP to be spam.

Comment: It wasn't deleted when I flagged it, so there was no way I could have known he would delete it later.

Comment: @BhargavRao ROFL `punch`. Fits perfectly there!

Comment: Regex withdrawal is a scary thing.

Comment: @JustinTime but there *is* hope! Traverse this finite state automaton with the following input to find the number to call for help.

Comment: @Kyll, You can usually/often get these from [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/40075130/regex-url-blogger).  Here is a bookmarklet which will open Google's cache for the page you are currently viewing: `javascript:void(window.open('http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:'+location.href.replace(/https?:\/\//,'')))`

Comment: @Kyll ["Punch a user" button](http://stackapps.com/questions/3802/punch-a-user-button)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This looks like a horribly, terribly, atrociously made post. Not spam though.
The question could be edited to the following:

> Using a regex in PHP, how can I extract the `contentId` parameter value from such a URL:
>
> > http://www.example.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=foo
>
> And store it in a variable?

It would still probably be a duplicate.
Don't feel too bad about misidentifying it though, it was really really bad.

Note that if you're unsure about whether or not a post is spam, you can come ask into [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).
It's a chatroom in which users fight spam and discuss moderation matters using [robots](http://socvr.org/faq#what-are-all-those-bots-doing-there) and waffles.
<sub><sub>mainly waffles</sub></sub>

Comment: This interpretation is far too charitable. With this logic, there is effectively no such thing as spam. All the spammer/bot needs to do is insert a couple of key words that might appear in a programming question, like regex and PHP. From there, you'll just fill in all the blanks, overlook the fact that it is an obvious spammy link, and waste a bunch of time trying to edit the post, with the unfortunate net effect of keeping crap visible on the site. Please stop trying to be so nice.

Comment: @CodyGray You may want to check some posts marked _true positive_ by the community on [Metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/posts) to see if there's "no such thing as spam" by this logic. I'd rather not take any chance to nuke some innocent post with red flags and provoke the associated penalty on the account. As usual, [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) is the first thing I consider in those cases. Finally, this link led to some anime video, not a website trying to sell hormone drugs or IT counselling or whatever.

Comment: @Cody And that's our job as humans to make the distinction between a bad post and spam. It's counter-productive to flag every terrible question containing a link as spam, or you'd be pretty much flagging as spam a good bunch of questions. Might as well write a bot that flags them as spam under criteria like presence of link and character count. It is clear that the link in this specific question is not spam; as the question says, they want to store an id, and they provide a link as example. The only real problem with the link is that it wasn't formatted as code... Does that warrant spam flags?

Comment: Wow…I don't even know where to begin. First of all, I'm staying as far away as I can from the decisions made by the cabal that inhabits the SOVCR chat room and runs things like Metasmoke, so no, I'm not going to go dig through that list. Besides, what is it supposed to teach me? That you have arbitrary standards for what you consider spam? Not useful. "Be nice" is not a useful guideline for dealing with spammers, and not intended to be applied here. This is a red herring. Neither I nor Robert know what the video contained; we don't click on suspicious links on the Internet.

Comment: It absolutely does not matter what the link *contains*, it matters how it is presented. This post is unabashedly spam. If you have a problem with spam flags nuking accounts and providing penalties, then you should raise a Meta feature request asking for that policy to be changed. You aren't providing evidence that this isn't spam, you're arguing against the harshness of the response. Again, irrelevant. That isn't how you make a decision when casting a flag. And contrary to Tunaki's straw man, I do not suggest flagging every "bad post" as spam. Nor doing it algorithmically.

Comment: I'd say that, as humans, it's obvious that the post in question is spam by its very definition: unsolicited or junk postings. Most definitions speak of email, but there are plenty that include newsgroup postings; I'd say those are very applicable to us. No, the problem with the link isn't that it wasn't formatted as code. That wouldn't help at all! Even if the link were formatted as code, *it would still be spam*. Using formatting tricks to hide your spam doesn't make it any less spammy. It just makes it less obvious. Seeing the reaction here, it's little wonder the site is full of garbage.

Comment: @Cody *and runs things like Metasmoke* First, that's wrong; it doesn't. Second, this project is going to be integrated into SE itself, so if you disagree with it, now might be the time to post your own Meta posts. *That you have arbitrary standards for what you consider spam?* Nope, the site definition of spam. And in this case, it simply isn't: there is no affiliation, there is no product placement, there are no revenue; just a link as example. The definition has always been the same, and it appears you want to change it, that's great, but, again, time for you to post your own Meta posts.

Comment: *You aren't providing evidence that this isn't spam* You're holding the wrong tail here: _you_ need to provide evidence of spam, not the contrary; and so far, there isn't. Where's the affiliation? Where's the gain of the OP to post this link? Is there some revenue is advertisement somewhere that you know about? If the link bothers you... just edit it. Problem solved. And you do suggest to flag every bad post as spam, you said so yourself: *Please stop trying to be so nice*.

Comment: Finally, *Seeing the reaction here, it's little wonder the site is full of garbage* that is very low and I'm afraid if you reach this level of criticism, there is nothing more to discuss. I could point you [to the moderation tools at your disposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333515/why-this-naa-flag-was-declined/333519#comment389879_333519) that you clearly do not use....  No wonder the site is full of garbage when the people that have the tools to do something about it, do not.

Comment: @CodyGray *"Be nice" is not a useful guideline for dealing with spammers, and not intended to be applied here.'* Law, and stuff like that, is based on intention, and as Tunaki wrote above, on the burden of proof being on the the accuser, not the accused. Your strategy is never used in domains where this stuff actually matters (where we have rule of law, i.e. civilized nations), why not just use that same concept here?

Comment: I'm kind of tired of the [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) being used as a bludgeon. It says nothing about marking things as spam. It doesn't say I have to follow random links to make sure that the user isn't affiliated or that money is being made off of it. All it says is "Don't be rude; be welcoming to newcomers; don't be a jerk". The burden is, in fact, on the *poster of the link* to prove it is not spam. After all, to use the same hammer, one of the sentences from that be nice article is *"If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you."*.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No one is saying that these posts are ok, you can always flag them as VLQ, downvote, close-vote/delete.

Comment: @Alex I wasn't saying that anyone was saying they are okay. I was saying that "Be nice" shouldn't be used to not mark a question with random links to who knows where as spam.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I can't see that requiring intent and reasonable burden of proof on the accuser is *being nice*, I see it as a basic feature of rule of law.

Comment: @Alex 1) This is a privately-owned Q&A site, not a court of law. 2) The moderators have the final say on whether something is spam, and there is a way of asking for reversal. The system works fine, everything is fine, I'm fine, how are you?

Answer (score 4):

Looks that all [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7014593/ricardo-silva?tab=questions) from this user are the same kind; get the query parameters from a video URL.

So despiste the fact that this is probably not a good one, the question itself it's probably not spam (by the way at first look it seems also spam to me).

Anywise the user can do some things to avoid the possible confusion of it question with spam:

1. Use a humorous-stupid-whatever URL: Since the problem is how to parse the URL to get for example the query id, don't not use a real DNS use something like http://chucknorris.org/some?id=XXXXX. Or less suspicious http://127.0.0.1/some?id=XXXX.
2. If you URL is not intended to be clicked; then format as code: `http://127.0.0.1/some?id=XXXX`. This not avoid that some user copy&paste the URL in the browser but at least it keep less obvious.

As @Yakk comments, of course this does not guarantees that someone can shadow a malware link on some licit question... but this not only applies for help question about URL manipulation, in fact you can put any malware link to a supposed [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr4xqbra/) for example.

Comment: The exact same video URL, and nearly indistinguishable questions.  How is that not something someone seeking idiots to click on a malware link or similar would do?

Comment: @Yakk yup... right :). But this is a problem in the whole site not only with this kind of questions, in fact you can put what link you want everywhere on the site isn't it?. Anyway I didn't click on the link (and I won't do it) so I'm only interpreting that it's not spam and are only bad questions but I see your point (and you could be totally right).

Comment: @Yakk Note that when seeing slightly more elaborated spam (like, anything above _"BUY DEM DRUGS"_) it's often useful to use a moderator flag and explain the situation. In that case, one could go with the following flag on one of this user's questions: `This user has posted multiple very low-quality questions which all contained fishy external links ([links to other questions]). I am not entirely sure if this is spam and am thus raising this flag instead.` The added context can help diamonds make the best possible call relative to the situation.