# Should a question remain open simply because it's cited as a source in a published work?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

While reading Mark Seeman's book, ["Dependency Injection in .NET"](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net), I discovered he'd quoted a question from Stack Overflow that related to explaining DI to a person in very simple terms, and he'd cited the question as a reference:

[How to explain dependency injection to a five-year-old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638919/how-to-explain-dependency-injection-to-a-5-year-old)

I looked up the question, and I was surprised to find that the question was closed, and -- earlier this year, even -- deleted.

I understand that there may be valid reasons to close and delete the question, but is there any precedent where a question remains open and undeletable when it's referenced in a published work, for historical purposes?  If not, then should there be?  I can't think of any other type of citable reference that has the ability to be "deleted".  This outcome has become possible with the advent of the internet, web 2.0, etc.

P.S. -- I think maybe this question belongs on SE meta, but I figured I'd start here since the referenced question is on SO.

Comment: This is always the risk when you reference a source from the internet. It can be deleted. Same with wikipedia articles etc. I don't think just because someone referenced some answer somewhere that they should get special treatments.

Comment: I don't know of a precedent, but at the basis we fundamentally set our own rules to preserve (or even improve) the quality of our own site. An external link to our content should not influence that. Where would you draw the line? Does the external resource need to be "good" (for whatever measure of good)? Does it merely need to exist? How do we know it does? Etc. etc.

Comment: @Bart -- Much like the arbitrary nature with which some laws are applied -- e.g. extremely old-fashioned, out-dated laws are often not enforced -- isn't there room to make exceptions when a preponderance of individuals agrees that it should be so?  Rules are not meant to be strictly followed without considering the benefits or disadvantages to the greater good.

Comment: *I can't think of any other type of citable reference that has the ability to be "deleted".* - Books (and other physical media) go out of print all the time.

Comment: @BSMP -- Bad example.  They still *exist*; even if every copy were burned, the library of congress would still have one.

Comment: *"isn't there room to make exceptions when a preponderance of individuals agrees that it should be so"* ... sure, if you get the community to agree in huge numbers if you were to make such a feature request, perhaps such a change can be made. I'm hard-pressed to believe this will happen however, given that in this specific case the question is simply bad in terms of scope established by that same community over the many years this site exists.

Comment: *They still exist* - Are you suggesting that every book, magazine, pamphlet, and newspaper *ever* printed still exists? And that those existing copies are easily accessible to the general public?

Comment: Just for the record, I largely agree with all of you here.  I just wanted to open this up for discussion.  The great comments and answer(s) here have certainly pushed me closer to the general consensus.

Comment: @BSMP -- boy wouldn't that be great.  No, but libraries everywhere do their best to do just that.

Comment: @Glorfindel -- My ulterior motive :)

Comment: @rory.ap Libraries do their best to preserve the content that *they feel is most valuable*, recognizing that they cannot preserve everything ever made.

Comment: SO is probably the most visible example for the thoroughly modern way that information is distributed to programmers.  Having it bogged down because Mark chose the neolithic dead-tree approach with no decent way to update stale info makes no sense.  In an ideal world, book authors would publish through e-books with automatic updates, distributed at the actual cost with the proceeds benefiting just the author.  It might happen some day.

Comment: Well, anyway, I think this is distracting us from a larger point here: if a book is widely-valued (like Mr. Seeman's), that should weigh more-heavily in citizens' positions on whether the question should remain or not.

Comment: @HansPassant -- I like your vision.

Comment: If that question were asked today, it would've been deleted without second thought. It's disappointing it's already accumulated a reopen-vote... The question has been deleted without issues for over 6 months. Do we really need to dreg up old junk like that? Let it rest in peace.

Comment: @rory.ap nah, the author should simply realize that web content could disappear at any time, and as such they have the obligation to keep their own content relevant, possibly by making use of the fairly liberal license used by SO.

Comment: @rory.ap: It doesn't matter if a book, my cat, or the president of the intergalactic federation quotes a SO question. We judge a question based on it's merits. Not on external factors.

Comment: @Cerbrus -- see my first comment, above.

Comment: _"isn't there room to make exceptions when a preponderance of individuals agrees that it should be so"_ <-- A _"a preponderance of individuals"_ agreed it should have been deleted, before.

Comment: @Cerbrus -- My comment stands regardless of how the citizens have voted *in this particular case*.  In that comment, I was addressing comments like yours that "we judge a question based on it's merits. Not on external factors.".  I agree that, in this case, the majority feels it should have been closed before; I was arguing that if the community feels that an external factor should come into play, then *it should* because the community has deemed it so.

Comment: The community doesn't seem to feel that way, though. Even then, we shouldn't simply dismiss SO's rules, if the community "feels like it".

Comment: I find it somewhat odd to see the many comments and answers on this question upholding the right of SO to delete content, but when you suggest that a crappy question with a link and not much else get deleted ([Why was this spam flag declined for an incoherent post with a link to a video?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336742/215552)) the Preservationist Coalition jumps down your neck...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You were trying to delete it as spam, not because it was a bad quesiton that doesn't meet the site's quality standards.  If you tried to flag this post as spam you'd get your flag declined just as quickly because *it's not spam*, even if it merits deletion for unrelated reasons.  Notice how the post you flagged as spam *was* deleted, and nobody bothered to try to undelete it or claim it's important that it be here, they just told you that it's not *spam*.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't trying to delete anything. And I wasn't suggesting that this question should be deleted as spam. The point I was making in the comments there was that it shouldn't be incumbent on ordinary users to examine the links posted to determine whether they are spam. The point I'm making here is that it seems like we have different standards of whether to delete things. I should have mentioned the whole idea of "historical lock" as evidence of the shifting winds of the delete-or-not storm.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You were trying to delete that other question as spam.  So  you *were* trying to delete something.  I never said you were advocating deletion of the question posted here.  Your assertion that someone shouldn't determine if a post is spam when flagging it for spam is not relevant to this discussion.  Your reason that people have different standards for deletion doesn't hold; people weren't opposed to deleting the question you wanted to delete, they just opposed your reason of "spam".  As for historical locks; they're not new at all.  They've been around for *many* years.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: That's not the preservationist coalition, it's the flag lawyers. The contradiction you point out is well-spotted, though it's not certain that the same people are involved.

Comment: You *could* flag it and ask a mod to undelete and historical lock, citing the book as a reason.  Not saying they would, but it's always an option.

Comment: @Will -- That has already happened.  See Brad Larson's answer.

Answer (score 21):

The question unquestionably shouldn't be opened just because someone is citing it.  The question *very* clearly merits closure, and nothing about someone citing it changes that.  Questions are closed/open based on whether they're appropriate questions for the site.

It being cited by a well circulated source would be something to *consider* when determining if it merited *deletion*.  That the person decided to cite it likely means that *they* think that there is useful information there, which is at least something to consider, although that doesn't mean that others can't disagree with that person over the value of the post.

Of course, if the author of that article really feels that this content is valuable, they are free to reproduce the content themselves (so long as they cite it appropriately) even if SE feels that the content isn't worth hosting.

Answer (score 16):

> *"Should a question remain open simply because it's cited as a source in a published work?"*

### Nope.

It doesn't matter if a book, my cat, or the president of the intergalactic federation quotes a SO question. We judge a question based on its merits. Not on external factors.

In other words, if a question isn't of sufficient quality to stay on SO, it *should* be deleted.

Comment: "If a question isn't of sufficient quality to stay on SO, it should be deleted" <-- unless the community at large agrees that it *should not* be deleted.  For example, in Devon CT, ["It is unlawful to walk backwards after sunset."](http://www.dumblaws.com/laws/united-states/connecticut).  Should that law be enforced?

Comment: @rory.ap: You're comparing ancient BS laws with SO rules. That's not very fair. I'm not going to to debate that.

Comment: Who are you to say that law is BS?  It's because you've judged it so; it's your opinion.  My point is only that if the community decides there should be an exception to the rule (which, I completely agree does not apply to the above-mentioned question), then shouldn't the exception stand?

Comment: _"if the community decides there should be an exception to the rule, then shouldn't the exception stand"_ Is a different meta question than what's going on here. You made it about the dependency injection question, when you linked said question. Of course everyone's going to agree ridiculous laws shouldn't be enforced. My point is that SO's rules and guidelines aren't ridiculous. They're not even on the same planet as the "walking backwards" one you linked.

Comment: Well, I'm not a robot.  My position has evolved during this great discussion.  See my comment above "Just for the record, I largely agree with all of you here. I just wanted to open this up for discussion. The great comments and answer(s) here have certainly pushed me closer to the general consensus."

Comment: I'm not saying you are a robot. Just that you're comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 6):

Should such a question remain open? No, a question of "What is a good dependency injection tutorial?" squarely falls under the modern close reason of

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

and was under the more general "not constructive" reason when Will was flagged down to close it back in the day.

However, I strongly disagree with the deletion of this question, because I see value in the answers there. As a result, I've voted to undelete and have placed a historical lock on the question. That allows it to be used as a reference while indicating that it's not representative of the questions you'll find here.

A question can both be off topic and still have value that makes it worth preserving. Closing a question marks whether or not it's appropriate for the site, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it should be deleted.

Comment: This answer exactly summarizes my viewpoint about questions like that.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm strongly against this decision. The content isn't "lost" by any metric. It's available to anyone that wants it. The value isn't "lost", just elsewhere not in SO.

Comment: The question has been deleted for __6 months__... Only to be undeleted because _this question_ drew attention to it. I don't get why stuff like this __has__ to be preserved. It was deleted, so why not just leave it be?

Comment: @Braiam - I don't see how deleting this content makes the Internet a better place. In what way does it improve the site?

Comment: BTW, and just for the laughs, the top answerer republished his own content with an arguably better title on his own site. https://johnmunsch.com/2013/05/19/explaining-closures-to-a-five-year-old/

Comment: @BradLarson: _"I don't see how bringing this content back after 6 months makes the Internet a better place. In what way does it improve the site?"_ (Sorry, childish reply, I know)

Comment: Simply. The internet gave two darns about it. He was going his happy merry way without it. Why must you hurt SO, *us*, to provide a content that was elsewhere and the internet saw absolutely no need for it at large.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Explaining why it's taken so long to bring up is easy: visibility. Once something is deleted, it's no longer public and no longer in search results. It takes someone coming across a dead link and realizing it's no longer there, then filing a complaint. Working to get something undeleted is much more difficult than getting something reopened.

Comment: I'm asking why it __has__ to be preserved. Not why it took that long to undelete.

Comment: In this world of hurt, broken links to broadly cited resources is a worse sin than keeping a few kilobytes of text in your database.

Comment: @tripleee: "Broadly cited"? Do you know of more sources than the one the OP here mentioned?

Comment: @Cerbrus I just googled.

Comment: *"In what way does it improve the site?"* By explicitly removing content that is so poor that these days it would be nuked on sight. *"What is a good dependency injection tutorial? I found a ton on Google, but none of them that would assume the reader is just a Java beginner."*  ... that is what you locked? That is what is preserved now on the site? It's plain terrible as a question, with a title that doesn't match. It doesn't fit any form of scope. All we have now is a turd that is allowed to exist for the benefit of a site out of our control. If that's the criterion, we're in trouble,

Comment: @Bart - The question is not what I saved here, but the answers. There are some good ones in there, good enough that they've received hundreds of votes and been referenced externally. It's the same reason I decline almost all requests by students to delete questions of theirs that received good, upvoted answers. I believe in preserving answers that others have found to be of value.

Comment: Then as a bare minimum at least edit it to a point where it no longer just asks for an off-site resource. Nobody reads the box about the historical lock. So at the very least give it a somewhat  more acceptable front for those entering the site at that question. As it stands, it's problematic.

Comment: @Bart - Fair enough. I took a stab at editing the question to focus on what was really being asked. I think that brings it closer to being within site scope. Might have been a different story had someone done that to begin with.

Comment: What confuses me is why the question, in its original state, got so many friggin up votes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking the wrong question here.

> Should a question remain open simply because it's cited as a source in a published work?

No. A thousand times, no. Questions get closed on SO for 3 basic reasons

1. It's not about programming
2. It's already been asked and answered (duplicate)
3. It's not really answerable

This falls into that third category. Specifically it falls into two subcategories of unanswerable

- It wants an off-site resource (draws links, which can fall out of date)
- It's opinion based (promotes [chit chat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTJmVyk9Aa4))

Maybe it IS a good question in general, but it can't be answered in a simple QA format like SO provides. SO isn't [about that](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

In other words, reopening it would just draw more and more posts over time that would likely require moderation. It's not worth it.

I like the quoted answer, tho. It's really good actually. But open? No

What you really need here is a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for). This question was asked in 2009, when some of these rules didn't exist. Let's run through the criteria

> The post is Off-Topic or Not Constructive

Yep. Just covered that

> The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature

It has a good, note-worthy answer, and a book chose to quote it

> There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post

55k views. 790 upvotes.

> The post is contentious; e.g., it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once

And it's been Meta-effected so it's been undeleted and deleted again.

What needs to happen is a mod can undelete it and then lock it. If a mod doesn't do that, though, it should remain deleted, or else it will get into a close/reopen war. You can flag it and ask for that to happen.

Comment: Lock is unnecessary, SE has no qualms on deleting content so long is available elsewhere: *I'm not saying **we need to have this question**, I agree that it's not optimal for many reasons. What I'm saying is, I'm not deleting another one like this **until we have some place to put what useful information it contains.*** The information is available elsewhere were it isn't responsibility of SO users to curate and maintain it.

Answer (score -1):

What a brilliant question. And yes, the DI post itself **should** remain available. I find having it closed/readonly - as it is currently - is a good compromise for those who argue it doesn't fit the rules.

I use this SO question about DI to teach my students about DI. And indeed I actually DID read about it in Mark Seeman's book as well (even before I was a CS teacher) :). But my below rant is actually regardless of how many off-site links this question has, digital or not.

#### At least some people value this item

When reading all the haters response here now that argue to delete that SO post, I'm  retroactively happy that I could still find it quickly today during my class as supporting source for my explanation. It is true that this question might be better suited for Quora or similar other sites. And if it IS deleted then I'll just have to point my students there, and Mark Seeman will have to create a new edition of his book. But personally I'd hate to see it go.

#### What's wrong with organic behaviour?

Remarks of the haters here like that in an ideal world there would be only e-books that stay in perfect sync I find plain ridiculous. The world is organic, the internet is organic, W3C standards are determined organically. Rewriting history to fit your definition of perfect is just closed minded and - frankly - dangerous. Perhaps you should read Orwell's [1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four) if you haven't (or reread it if you have). We don't need a 'ministry of truth'.

#### To err is human - and it has value (at least if you learn from it)

Failure is human. So, even if you delete this post, any new DI-learning or questioning fool might just ask this same question again here. It's much stronger argument to add a comment in which you reference them to this closed-off but still accessible SO item as an example. It's unrealistic to think that eventually everybody will somehow know only to ask "uninteresting tech/syntax-only" questions on SO (I'm exaggerating, I know). You'll have to wait until the singularity occurred, at which point Stackoverflow will be pretty useless, as the super AI's don't make programming mistakes, or buggy frameworks.

Striving for perfection is great, but please gracefully accept historic failures, deviations and "questions that didn't fit the rules". The "rules" will never be perfect either. A good answer to an inappropriate question has at least historical value.

Answer (score -5):

I'm not sure what is your issue... Do we have to undelete content merely because it's linked elsewhere? Of course not. Do we want content that doesn't fit the guidelines that allowed Stack Overflow to be as successful as it is and will continue to be if kept? Obviously not. Do all resources have to be on Stack Overflow? Nope, it's a fools errand. Can you simply copy the content? Yes you can, if you provide proper attribution.

I see this as a no-op. You have the power to solve your problem as individual and community intervention isn't needed. You have that power, use it.

Comment: @rory.ap is *your due diligence* to know what are the alternatives approaches to your problem. Instead of jumping down to solve the problem, verify that a problem exist in first place. You assert that the content is "lost", when you haven't actually searched for it. That's why it is lazy.

Comment: @Braiam: The fact that something can be found by searching through a large dump of random stuff does not mean that it shouldn't be considered "lost". Furthermore, as rory said several times, it's not just about this one question. He's asking about general policy, using this as an example.

Comment: "*Do we want content that doesn't fit the guidelines that allowed Stack Overflow to be as successful as it is and will continue to be if kept? Obviously not.*" Says who? As far as I'm concerned, if it is genuinely useful information, and it did fit the site's guidelines *at the time*, then it should not be *deleted*. It should be closed and locked from future edits. But deleting useful content does not *in any way* make the Internet a better place.

Comment: @NicolBolas the content isn't "lost" it's available to anyone that has the dedication to actually search for it. **SO doesn't have to host it all**. It's simply not sustainable!

Comment: @Braiam: "*it's available to anyone that has the dedication to actually search for it.*" Again, just because you could find something doesn't mean it isn't lost. Reasonably accessible content does not require "dedication" to find. "*SO doesn't have to host it all. It's simply not sustainable!*" Why not? What's "not sustainable" about it? Since deleted content doesn't actually disappear, SO's servers still must store it. So... what's the problem with making it visible to all?

Comment: @NicolBolas that it isn't SO purpose. Yes, it changed with the years (and we learned what doesn't/do work), but that doesn't mean that we shouldn't remove cruft that doesn't fit the guidelines anymore, if we want to keep being a repository of high quality Q&A focused site.

Comment: @Braiam: I fail to see how locking a few old questions that clearly provide useful information in any way keeps SO from being "a repository of high quality Q&A focused site."

Comment: @NicolBolas because the most powerful way to influence people is with examples. Not having examples of what shouldn't be done is more powerful signal of keeping examples of what should not be done. People considers "unfair" that their question is deleted but "that other" is not.

Comment: @Braiam: That's why historical locks have a big sign on them saying that they're kept around for historical purposes only. And if a few people complain anyway... so what? We close their MSO questions as duplicates of the existing one and move on. That's a small price to pay to keep genuinely useful content and links around.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not sure if you are joking... haven't you seen plenty of cases where the OP uses a closed (not even locked) question as example of why theirs should be allowed? Read one here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280826/why-does-bill-the-lizard-lock-all-the-good-questions

Comment: @Braiam: I never said that people don't do that. I said that it's a small price to pay.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's contradictory. Why should we shoot ourself in the foot promoting the kind of content we close and delete by keeping them undeleted? Shouldn't our efforts be more effective if we don't have to worry about those?!

Comment: @Braiam -- Quoting Brad Larson:  "A question can both be off topic and still have value that makes it worth preserving. Closing a question marks whether or not it's appropriate for the site, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it should be deleted."  And, I don't think anyone has to "worry" about that question.  Why would it be worrisome?

Comment: @Braiam: You highly exaggerate the price being paid here. The "shooting ourself in the foot" is merely a couple of MSO posts that we have to close. This is not some huge burden to the community. It's not like the number of these questions increases with time, after all, since we close such questions nowadays quite expediently. We're talking about a fixed set of questions.