# Why don't we just delete crappy questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, low-quality-posts, quality-improvement

Something that has bothered me ever since I joined the Stack Overflow community is the large number of awful questions. I know that if a question is low quality, it will get closed, but the question still stays on the site cluttering it up unless a moderator or the OP deletes it.

So here's my question: When a post is marked as a duplicate, or closed as "off-topic" or "unclear what you're asking", why doesn't it just get deleted or at least made invisible? If it's not helpful to the site why can we still see it while browsing the tags?

Comment: There are various paths towards this content being removed. Also note, that most of these types of posts only generate a few dozen views per year, so the exposure isn't quite as grand as it is being made out to be.

Comment: As a note, users with enough reputation (10k+) can vote to delete questions after they've been closed a certain amount of time. (2 days) That time is to give the OP a chance to edit/fix their question, if at all possible. If the question is bad enough, users with 20k+ rep can vote to delete -3 or lower scored questions immediately after closure.

Comment: So basically I just need to increase my reputation and start deleting these? `:-)`

Comment: @MDXF In any practical sense, no, because you'd still need two other people with 20k to also vote to delete them, and the odds of two more people also finding the post and wanting to delete it tend to be low in most cases.  Realistically you'd need to be a mod to actually result in questions being deleted.

Comment: I think this would help http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333477/792066

Comment: What @Servy, plus you'd have to find a way to stop people from answering and/or up-voting terrible questions, and up-voting answers to terrible questions. That is what keeps a lot of the crap alive.

Comment: My teachers always taught me 'there's no such thing as a crappy question, only crappy answers'.

Comment: @StijndeWitt Here are some examples of just how crappy some questions are (and to everyone else, *even when they have answers or comments*. We've got crap like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628702/may-i-know-how-do-i-convert-these-c-codes-to-java) with an answer, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176938/what-is-this-codes-output) with 5 comments and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538511/what-means-p-argument-in-a-mkdir-command) that probably should be on Unix & Linux SE. These provide no value to the community and I feel that they just need to... go away.

Comment: @MDXF Your second example, in particular, is not very representative: it was posted last week (and will soon be deleted, as per Glorfindel's answer), and the five comments are rightfully ripping the question apart (so there is nothing wrong with them).

Comment: The reason they're left alone, to my knowledge, is so that someone else with the same question can google it, and find that crappy question, instead of asking a duplicate of it; ideally, they'll also find an answer that solves their problem.  The existence of the Reversal badge indicates that this is considered useful by the guys in charge.  Unfortunately, a lot of people don't actually do this, which renders it less useful than it could be.  And if the question is _really_ bad, or unhelpful in any way, it'll just end up deleted.

Comment: @MDXF about the UL question, that would be downvoted there *too*.

Comment: @Braiam I agree, but at least it would be on-topic.

Comment: With regard to duplicates, it can be useful to have the added keywords linking to a good question for future searchers. If all duplicates were just deleted you would lose those keywords.

Comment: While I agree that it is nice to clean up the site, bear in mind that "deleting" posts doesn't actually delete them, it merely makes them invisible to non-members (including search engines) and members with <10k rep. Those with 10k+ (and moderators) can still see them (although they do have a distinctive background colour so you can tell they've been deleted).

Comment: @StijndeWitt What your teacher actually meant was that she's paid to answer your questions, regardless of how crappy they are, so you should feel free to ask any question that you want to ask, because she's not allowed to refuse to answer it because of its quality.  Of course, when you're asking questions of people who aren't paid to answer your questions, then they may well decide that your question isn't worth answering if it isn't of an acceptable level of quality.

Comment: See: [How does deleting work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/191655)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

We don't delete them, to give the author a chance to improve his/her question so that it conforms to the Stack Overflow standards. If this doesn't happen, [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) kicks in after a few days:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

If the question is utter crap, [trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (>20k rep) can vote to delete the question immediately after closure, and [slightly less trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (>10k rep) after two days.

Comment: What about [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419997/what-is-wrong-in-this-i-am-trying-to-declare-a-pointer)? or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360781/how-to-write-a-function-that-reads-and-retrieves-a-single-integer)? There are so many examples...

Comment: @MDXF Those posts have upvoted answers, so they won't be automatically deleted.

Comment: @MDXF - A combined 200 views over 2 years on those posts, I don't see how that is necessarily problematic.

Comment: @TravisJ Until you multiply it by a few million questions with the same problem.

Comment: @TravisJ [6214 views and a 1-vote answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549753/scanning-and-printing-a-character-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @MDXF and ... they're gone. Good riddance!

Comment: @Servy - That is a rather large brush to paint with here, perhaps if there were actual stats to back up that 2 million posts need to be deleted I would be more inclined to agree. Do you really think that 20% of the content here is crap?

Comment: Often questions with low views or with complex issues do not receive voting of any kind. This does not immediately make them "crap". A more indicative query would have focused on answers as well as voting, and included 0 voted posts. As it is much easier to recognize something wrong with a post than it is to corroborate the issue raised, often decent posts will sit at 0 votes.

Comment: Put another way, if you were to have removed all of the posts except the 3,333,350 posts noted, a great disservice would have been done to the site.

Comment: @TravisJ Sure, no doubt some of those questions aren't crap and don't actually merit deletion.  Perhaps even the majority of them would have some value, but it's certainly pretty strong supporting evidence to there being a *lot* of low quality content not being deleted.  You're the one asserting that virtually all of those ~9 million posts are valuable, and that there couldn't be a notable minority of them that actually aren't, despite the fact that not a single person has felt the need to indicate that they thought it was useful.

Comment: @Servy - Well, you indicated 20% was worthy of deletion, which would leave roughly 10,000,000 remaining and delete 2.4 million posts. Certainly it is possible that some of these posts warrant deletion, however, judging a question merely by its vote count and not including the answers posted there throws out a very, very, **very** large amount of signal and essentially amounts to either being naive or flat out disingenuous towards improving content.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree, there's a reason why we have a [Reversal badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal).

Comment: @TravisJ What's your basis for assuming that virtually all of the posts for which not even a single person has indicated that they are valuable are all worth keeping, and that there isn't even a notable minority of posts there that would merit deletion?  There is no evidence at all that there is value there.  Some will, of course, but to just assume (without any evidence to support your position, because apparently it's okay for  you to make such sweeping assumptions without evidence, even in the face of evidence that contradicts you) that approximately *all* of them are valuable.

Comment: @Servy - Again, in a word, for the third time, **answers**. If you have a post with a 0 vote and no answer which has sat languishing, then by all means, wipe it out.

Comment: *"If the question is utter crap, trusted users (>20k rep) can delete the question immediately"* - That should read more like *"If the question is utter crap, trusted users (>20k rep) **can vote** to delete the question immediately"*. Just a bit of clarification.

Comment: Well, not quite, it *first* takes 5 users to close the question, at least 3 users to downvote the question, *then* 3 trusted users to vote to delete it.  Having to have so many users involved when getting rid of crap is certainly a core reason why it doesn't happen often enough.  With the added the wrinkle that the crappier the question (especially the title), the less likely those users will show up.  So SO users optimize their questions to be as crappy as possible, basic survival of the fittest.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you're right, thanks.

Comment: @Glorfindel You're welcome.

Comment: "has no pending reopen votes" So when voting to close a question that is destined for the Roomba it's a Good Idea to make sure it doesn't have a pending suggested edit. Otherwise, there's a good chance that someone will approve the edit, which will bump it into the reopen queue. And if the OP actually fixes the question after that, making it worthy of re-opening, it _won't_ go back into the reopen queue again. (I expect you know this Glorfindel, this comment is for the benefit of other readers).

Comment: @TravisJ [20% crap is an underestimate.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) Depending on the tag, I would say many times more than half of all questions are just sad unhelpful pleas for help.

Comment: And this is why when you need a **very** bad question, you should downvote it **and** all the answers.   (Along with voting to close if the question is not already closed.)

Comment: @IanRingrose eh, in my experience downvoting all the answers too just results in the answerers upvoting each other, it's a losing battle.

Comment: Sigh, downvote all the answers? Why? That is like asking us to explain downvotes, it is just flat out wrong and has been proven time and time again to not have the support of the community. Please post such a point of view as an answer instead of hiding behind a comment so you can see the type of reaction from the community.

Answer (score 11):

Theoretically, "closed" is a temporary state.  A closed question should be either improved or deleted. However, only some questions are deleted automatically (more details in [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)). For example, if a question has an accepted answer or an upvoted answer, it won't be deleted automatically. Such questions can be deleted manually by [users with delete vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Moderators can delete questions too, but they rarely do so, because they have to handle things that can't be handled by community (for example comments flags).

It's a bit different with questions closed as a duplicate. In some cases it's better to keep them. See [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/):

> There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds people can find the answer they’re looking for.

Comment: "On Hold" is the temporary state - after a couple of days they're "Closed".

Comment: @Glorfindel "on hold" is a "more" temporary state—the difference from "closed" is that when such a question is edited, it goes into the reopen queue.

Comment: " A closed question should be either improved or deleted" -- or be kept as a signpost duplicate, if that applies.

Comment: @duplode Right, I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

We actively delete questions via Community Moderation. We tend to focus on delete candidates that have or will survive [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) so as to preserve the few votes we are allotted.

For those with 10k+ rep and the Delete Privilege, we have access to the [10k Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFza4.jpg) screen. It is quite basic, though, without even simple filtering and searches.

We have chat rooms that call out various questions to consider for deletion.

And we write bots to identify delete candidates for others to consider. In particular attempting to address some of the shortcomings of the 10k Tools screen.

If you have delete votes available, feel free to stop on by the [Campaigns](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) room to assist whenever you get a chance. Ping one of us. Odds are you will get a list shortly thereafter. A list without bias that you will need to work and apply your own common sense and choice.

As always use your best judgment in preserving good content. Do No Harm. Because the question may not be crappy and might deserve another chance.

Answer (score 1):

One aspect to consider about deleting every closed post is those that are closed as duplicates. The reason those are kept is that while the content can be found elsewhere, the phrasing of the question might be different than the question it is duplicating. It's still useful for the closed question to exist as it allows people who phrased their question differently to find the actual easily through a google search.

Comment: Probably most of them don't need [4726 signposts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/218384) (and counting)...

Answer (score -9):

#### Just leave them alone

I don't understand, and probably never will understand, this need from Stack Overflow community members to try and moderate these things beyond what the community already does automatically.

#### The search engines will solve this for you

'Crappy' questions will not get many answers. They won't get many votes. Comments on them tend to relate not to the subject, but to the quality of the question. People will not link to these questions from other questions or from blog posts. All this will result in crappy questions getting crappy search engine rankings. Stuff that does not appear in search results might as well not exist as far as the internet goes.

#### The opposite is also true

If a question gets linked to, gets valuable answers, gets ranked high in search engines etc... then who are we to judge that this question was in fact crappy? If it really was, then why the answers, links etc?

#### Time is the best moderator

I see questions with scores over a 100 being closed as off topic... If they really are off topic then where do the votes come from? Just let time and the existing community moderation do it's work. Crappy questions will automatically sink to the bottom.

Who here is going around undoing the 'bad moderation'? If a question has 100+ votes, why is it still closed? Is the public wrong? Or are SO mods stubborn?

Comment: You're assuming that every non-'crappy' question is on topic by virtue - that just isn't true. Content that isn't appropriate for the site can gather many upvotes, inbound links, etc, that doesn't mean it shouldn't be closed if it doesn't fit here

Comment: I'm assuming nothing but one thing: that the community will be less likely to write meaningful answers for, vote for, link to etc 'crappy' questions. Not being on-topic is just one of the many different ways in which questions can be 'crappy'. The community will automatically factor that in when dealing with these questions. *"Content that isn't appropriate for the site can gather many upvotes, inbound links, etc"*  If content really is not appropriate, why would people vote for it? The difference is that I believe visitors can decide for themselves what is appropriate or not.

Comment: Crappy means bad. Off-topic means doesn't belong here. They're very different things, one has obvious negative connotations and the other is just a neutral statement of fact. You can vote at 15 rep, and a user with 15 rep isn't necessarily experienced enough to know what's on or off topic. So it's not useful to take votes as a measure of appropriateness for the site, because that's not what they are; it's why we _have_ the other mechanisms. It sounds like you don't enjoy community-moderated content, but unfortunately that's what SO is

Comment: The downside of meta: only the mods come here so no one here ever wants to hear the voice of the public. Just visit some high-ranked questions that were closed as off-topic and read some comments there. Many people are feeling that SO is becoming over-moderated.

Comment: I'm not a moderator, I'm just one of the members of the public you're talking about. At some point you'll just need to accept you're in the minority. Trying to pretend that the lack of support for your opinion confirms your opinion isn't going to cut it I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh I'm not pretending anything. I just visit this site very regularly. What I'm seeing is that I see **a lot** of issues cloded, where the public is voting for these issues. Just now I googled up [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358817/best-practice-for-localization-and-globalization-of-strings-and-labels) with 67 votes (I just added one) and closed. If half the questions I encounter using Google are high voted but nonetheless closed, I conclude that moderation is overzealous. How much moderation should be applied **is** inherently opinion-based and my opinion differs.

Comment: @StijndeWitt "If half the questions I encounter using Google are high voted but nonetheless closed, I conclude that moderation is overzealous" -- That only follows if you assume moderation should be done according to public opinion.

Comment: Yeah, it just sounds more and more like you don't like the principals behind community moderation, and rules in general. That's fine, but any opinion like that is almost irrelevant here as you're going against the empirical purpose of the site, which is to be rule based and community moderated. I don't that paradox is likely to be resolved, the company and community have made it abundantly clear we want to keep moderating content.

Comment: @StijndeWitt: Please do not upvote off-topic questions.

Comment: "The difference is that I believe visitors can decide for themselves what is appropriate or not." Yes, 100 times! If I write just one thing on the next SO survey, it will be this.

Comment: @StijndeWitt If the majority of the questions you find in searches are closed, then it sounds like you're searching for the kinds of questions that we don't want here.  You simply are looking for content that is out of SO's scope of acceptable questions.

Comment: Regarding your comment "only the mods come here so no one here ever wants to hear the voice of the public", you'll notice that I'm the first moderator to comment anywhere on this post. In fact, I've argued for not deleting posts on multiple occasions ( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337030/19679 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332611/19679 ) and normal members of the community disagreed with me. There aren't enough elected moderators on the entire site to account for the votes on these answers. The community does have a voice on Meta, and moderators don't have special control over it.

Comment: @StijndeWitt ... You're right, but there are a small number of people who come here for power, not to help. Experts-Exchange thought that could live by charging for answers. Stack-exchange thinks they can live by removing useful questions. Yes, questions that are against SO's official policies - but if those don't change in 5 years, we'll be getting our IT answers from a different site in 10 years, one that sees the obvious truth you see here. (talking more about recommendations/opinions being 'off topic', not crappy questions, but you are right about that too - they're useful for Google bait)

Comment: Not only is your argument based on an overly simplistic model, your assertion that mods cause deletion is completely wrong. Mods are among the most anti-deletion people on meta. Perhaps familiarizing yourself with the reality here will allow you to analyze complex problems on the site better.

Comment: @FastAl "but if those don't change in 5 years, we'll be getting our IT answers from a different site in 10 years" -- Why would that be a problem? Who makes up the "we" you are talking about? Is it that difficult to understand that Stack Overflow is not meant to be all things to all people?

Comment: @BradLarson I'm sorry I used the term mods wrong.... When I use that term I mean people acting as mods, by exercising their regular accounts moderation powers... Not the actual elected mods. Sorry for the confusion.  **I've argued for not deleting posts on multiple occasions**  Thanks for that! I hope SO's policies evolve towards more of a live-and-let-live policy vs the current control-freakish policy (imnsho). Spam? Insults? Racism? Porn? By all means delete it. Real questions (albeit maybe 'crappy' ones)? Please just let it slide. The general public and search engines will deal with it

Comment: @duplode *Why would that be a problem?* This is what happens with over-moderation: a small group of regulars starts to make rules and policies more strict to cater for their specific needs, such as 'don't pollute the site', and in doing so slowly start turning the site into a niche...of a niche... of a niche as policies get stricter and stricter. 'Normal' SO users don't browse questions here... They hit them searching the web for answers. In doing so, they find a question that they actually know the answer to and add it. The group that lurks here daily is a minority.

Comment: @bjb568 Sigh. Don't worry I am familiar with Stack Overflow. It's just that the term 'mod' is broader than just SO you know? The mods are everywhere but only on SO do they get elected and what not. I'm actually an active mod on a couple of sites myself. On SO normal users have many powers that on other platforms only 'mods' have, so I use the term interchangeably.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll upvote anything I like thank you very much. This whole off-topic thing is just not my cup of tea. The fact that I'm a developer and found that question with Google (unlike you guys I *never* come here directly) proofs that it is, in fact, on-topic. Just that SO keeps narrowing the scope of what is considered on-topic. There a dozens of 500+ voted questions that would be considered off-topic if they were asked today...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I said I googled up an off-topic post and voted for it... maybe you won't believe me but I found that post, not because I was looking for an off-topic post to paste here, but because at almost any time I will have multiple browser tabs with SO answers open. I google for tech stuff **a lot** and I find these answers. Many of them closed as off-topic. And voted highly. It happens **all the time**. You can keep saying they are off-topic, but Google does not agree with you. These questions are **on-topic** for my searches.

Comment: @StijndeWitt [1/2] That is a false dichotomy. It is not a choice between letting a small cabal of regulars dictate what is acceptable according to their whims  versus leting anyone who visits the site do whatever they want. This sitebis open to anyone, as long as they respect a handful of fundamental principles that exist ever since Stack Overflow came into being. It is not a problem if someone rejects said principles -- they can go somewhere else and ask and discuss however they feel like. But they should not expect to impose their will on this community by force of numbers.

Comment: "google doesn't agree with you"? Ok, you're trying to take this in a very weird direction now. Of course google's algorithms don't dictate what is on and off topic on an unrelated Q*A site. I can't imagine what makes you think they do

Comment: @Clive *Ok, you're trying to take this in a very weird direction now.*  Yeah... the concept that off-topic vs on-topic is broader than SO and it's particular rules and guidelines is 'a very weird direction'. *Of course google's algorithms don't dictate what is on and off topic on an unrelated QA site.* Ehm you know that determining whether content is on-topic for a certain search query is the search engine's core business right? I visit Google every day asking programming related questions => Google finds answers to my questions on SO (no wonder as it's a programmer Q&A site) => on-topic

Comment: @StijndeWitt [2/2] I agree over-moderation is a bad thing, and we should be wary of overzealousness. But that doesn't mean giving up moderation out of fear of some bogeyman slippery slope. A community has the right to stand for its principles, and to resist mob rule.

Comment: @duplode *A community should have the right to stand for its principles* So what is that community in SO's case? I consider the whole of the public that visits SO a few times per year it's community... And on **many** questions the number of upvotes far outweighs the number of people that voted to close... So who is right?  Most people don't take the time to go onto meta to voice their opinion... they just see the Closed banner and add a comment that that sucks... But people on meta seem to ignore these comments because frankly, I feel like I'm a voice in the wilderness.

Comment: You're conflating two unrelated things. Either you understand that and you're doing it on purpose just to keep a basically-dead argument going, or you don't understand it and you're not going to, no matter how many people try to explain it to you. Either way I feel like I've been talking to a brick wall for a while now, so I'm out.

Comment: @StijndeWitt Let me hazard an analogy then (it is imperfect, but then again analogies are always imperfect). According to your view, it would seem, the community in the case of your GitHub repositories consists of everyone who can visit that site and is able to interact with said repositories. Does that mean you must accept any pull request with lots of +1's that comes your way, because rejecting them would be excluding part of the community?

Comment: @duplode Actually, yes. Of course in the case of an OSS software project on GitHub, I would consider actual users of the lib the community. And if some PR makes some sense (e.g. is not breaking stuff), even though I don't see the need myself, if the public is voting highly for this issue, I would consider it rude to ignore them and not apply the PR. At least I feel I would owe the public a good explanation for why I would feel they are all wrong and I am right. You see I have a lot of faith in humanity. That many people can't be all wrong.

Comment: @Clive Sorry you feel that way. I am not doing it on purpose I can assure you. I too feel like I'm talking to a brick wall but I guess that's because we are at very different angles of the spectrum here. I think whether questions are 'crappy', or 'off-topic' is inherently opinion based. It's not a hard science. Language tends to be slippery like that. It's not math. I'm not saying my *opinion* is fact. You on the other hand have been telling me about 'the facts' from your very first comments. I don't accept them as facts and I don't agree with your *opinion*. Now *that's* a fact.

Comment: That's cool, enough of us do accept them that the site will survive just fine. If the Yahoo Answers approach _does_ ever make it into SO proper, then it's all yours - me and my ilk will run away pretty quick I can promise you :)

Comment: Basically what you and duplode are saying (and multiple times) is that something must be wrong with me for not agreeing with these rules. SO is not for me. It almost sounds like you guys want me to go away... It's strange that as a full-time developer having tons of programming related questions, since the answers I find are closed as off-topic, this proofs SO is not for me, instead of indicating the policy has become *too* strict. If actual programming-related questions from actual programmers are off-topic for a programmers QA site, that should ring some bells...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to come across like that. I certainly don't want to drive you away, I guess I just believe in my opinion as strongly as you do in yours but reading back I could've phrased things more constructively. Let's leave it there, I won't change your mind and that's fine. If there _is_ a problem that some of us are too involved/close to be able to see, you've gone about raising it in the right way IMO. Good luck

Comment: @StijndeWitt [1/2] (1) "At least I feel I would owe the public a good explanation for why I would feel they are all wrong and I am right." -- In that case, you are rejecting the PR, and rightfully so. You shouldn't be forced into quitting your own project because a group of users disagree with you over a fundamental design decision. They can always fork if they must. (2) I fully agree with "it's not math", but that absolutely doesn't mean anything goes. Cf. law and philosophy for imperfect analogies in the world-at-large.

Comment: @StijndeWitt [2/2] (3) When you read my position as "he disagrees, therefore something must be wrong with him", you are assuming that I believe there is only One True Way of setting up a programming Q&A site. But I don't agree with that at all. Is Stack Overflow enough to cover all sorts of programming questions? No. it isn't. Is that a problem? Not at all, unless one dreams of a centralised source of knowledge that caters to everyone, satisfies everyone and makes all other approaches superfluous and doomed to Darwinian extinction. I find that both a pipe dream and a dangerous goal to have.

Comment: history shows that relying solely on community moderation and voting doesn't work, Atwood explained this in [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/):
"we discovered that these posts become so popular over time that they truly start to drown out everything else on the site... it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they *need* that power..."

Comment: @Clive Thanks for your kind words! Good luck to you as well!

Comment: @gnat Ok point taken, but there are tons of *real* questions, not 'easy and fun stuff' that are closed as well. It's just a fine balance (and impossible to satisfy everyone), but I think on SO the needle has been in the overmoderation part of the scale for a while now and it would be good if we would tone it down a little. It all comes down to finding the right amount of tolerance for *crappyness* I guess: too much and good stuff gets drowned in crap, too little and good stuff gets muffled.

Comment: _"You can keep saying they are off-topic, but Google does not agree with you. These questions are on-topic for my searches."_ What a nonsense. Google does not get to decide what the topic of this website is, and neither do you.

Comment: Google is a pretty objective measurement of on-topicness. Arguably more objective than any one of us here... It's just that SO redefines on-topic as ; fitting in the SO format / rules / guidelines', whereas Google just analyzes my search query and ranks answers found here according to that. We are actually just arguing whether my search query was 'on topic' in the first place. The interesting thing is that most of these queries will return both on-topic as well as 'off-topic' (in SO terms) answers...

Comment: Google has nothing to do with on-topicness, and if it ever had I wouldn't use it. Say, if I wanted to find about porn sites, last thing I'd need would be Google telling me that it's off-topic at SO. "Your search is closed because off-topic, bwa-ha-ha"

Comment: I said Google is an objective measure of *on-topicness* for a certain search query. Of course that doesn't mean stack overflow is on topic for any search you make. But I'm a programmer and I make **programming-related** search queries and I find answers here on Stack Overflow. They are on-topic for my programming related search query, but somehow not for SO, a programming-related QA site...