# Why was this spam flag on this question with an e-commerce link at the bottom declined?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, spam

I just flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404956/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-268435456-bytes-exhausted-in-query-fact) post. At first it appears to be a sans-mcve debugging request, but it contains the following passage near the bottom:

> we have more than 300k product,check this here Visit (redacted)?

The flag was promptly declined with the message:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Why is this not spam? If it is, in fact, spam, how do I share the evidence with the moderator to get the flag declination reversed?

Comment: That sentence you reference has this preceeding it: `I am wondering if it have something to do with the product QTY,`  The post does not appear to be spam.

Comment: @Daedalus I noticed that, but it seemed to me that that could be a sneaky way to disguise a post as something other than spam. The question appears to be unanswerable as posted, so what other purpose might it have...?

Comment: We'll need more evidence than that to qualify a post as spam.  I've seen many similar posts, where users have said they have a problem on their website, and link to the website as an example.  That doesn't mean they're spam.  As to the state of the post and whether or not it is answerable, it could simply be a bad question as well.  Those do exist.

Comment: I was going to link to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336742/why-was-this-spam-flag-declined-for-an-incoherent-post-with-a-link-to-a-video) as part of a witty observation that there is no consensus for the definition of "spam". Then I noticed that you are probably already aware of that.

Comment: It occurs to me, given the answers to this question, that perhaps we need to reconsider whether it is *actually* okay to link to the live website when asking a question about its design. That isn't allowed for other types of applications—you can't just link to your EXE and expect people to download it—and we already have a rule that requires questions to be self-contained with an MCVE. Why, then, *is* it considered acceptable to provide a link to the website? Why isn't that *the very definition* of spam? I guess the reason is we don't want a -500 rep penalty applied; that's a bad reason.

Comment: @cody I don't believe it was ever ok to link to live site without MCVE inline in the question. Problem demonstration is essentially guaranteed to disappear as soon as OP applies fix to live site.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clearly spam -- the user does seem to have a legitimate question, however badly presented -- but it is unnecessary. I've edited the link out of the question.

Comment: And the user edited it back in because apparently "i need expert to see how much categories and products i have". *Shrug*.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Now that is definitely inappropriate, and starts smelling a lot more like spam to me. Even if we take their comment at face value, there was no need for a link; simply naming some numbers would be more helpful than a link. I've rolled back their edit.

Comment: Beware Hanlon's razor: "never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity". Based on everything in this question it is my informed opinion that this user has no idea what he is doing. At all. I strongly suspect that he really thinks that the link adds information to the question that is required to fix the problem.

Comment: If a spammer has pure, non-malicious intentions, does that make their submissions not spam? If processed pig falls into a can, does it make a sound? Are we sure that we want the "spam" flag to be judging *intent*?

Comment: @CodyGray If you didn't *intend* to harm someone we call it an "accident", rather than "assault" or "murder" :-) So yes, I'd say that intent matters.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to link in the website, if there is a genuine question about it. Although it does seem a little gratuitous I agree.

However the OP has posted code and appears to be asking a genuine, although off topic question, as it lacks MVCE.